# How to display data attributes in columns?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I am looking for some help with displaying core data attributes (name, last name, city) from a core data model. I have one entity with 3 attributes and am trying to display them neatly in columns in a textview but the attributes are not aligned in columns. Now when i display the attributes all the fetched results come back in a non aligned way. Is there a way to do this ? thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a Core Data issue, it's a question of how to display data in a table. Answers would be the same whether or not Core Data were involved.

Comment: ah ok thanks for tip....any pointer for my issue ?

Comment: am starting to look at scrolling a scrollview with 3 textviews inside it but seems way out there.....

Comment: How about a table view with custom cells?  Each cell would have 3 text fields.  (That way, the table view looks after scrolling and caching of UI elements.)

Comment: Thank you Philip, your answer kinda put me on a track and did just that you suggested, i created a new view controller with a table  view in it and a custom cell class, took me the last four days to work out all the plumbing and connections but finally got it to work, now got myself a scrollable table with aligned attributes from my core data model. Was pretty steep though for a while but perseverance is a gift.Thank you, i'll mark up your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Philip's advice and followed his suggestion by implementing a tableview in view controller with a custom cell and managed to have a scrollable table with my attributes nicely aligned. As Tom had pointed out this was not a core data issue but more of newbie trying to align attributes.Thanks to them both.